# Looping through a list of Objects is not displaying properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops, object

I'm trying to display a loop of objects.  It's showing through `console.log`, but it's not showing on the browser.  My current code is as follows:

```
class Profile extends React.Component {
    renderList() {
        const { booking } = this.props;  
        booking && Object.keys(booking).map(x => {
            console.log("booking", booking[x].item_name);
            return <div>{booking[x].item_name}</div>
        })
    }
    render() {
        return (
        {this.renderList()}
        )
    }
}
```

I tried the `for` loop, `map` as well as lodash and I get the same result so I don't think it's the issue with the looping method of the object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need to return the elements. Try this:

```
class Profile extends React.Component {
    renderList() {
        const { booking } = this.props;  
        if (booking) {
            return Object.keys(booking).map(x => {
                return <div>{booking[x].item_name}</div>
            })
        }
        return null;
    }
    render() {
        return this.renderList();
    }
}
```

Probably `return bookings && Object.keys(booki...` will also work.

**Update:** `return ({ this.renderList() })` will give jsx syntax error, should be written as shown above.

Comment: Just wondering why that would give an error? Is it because it's a single line? Mine is wrapped in additional JSX elements and is not giving me an error

Comment: @Kevvv probably because there's no point of having a js expression template as the root. Like just return the expression itself because the template is required inside elements to let react know that "Hey this is JS inside these braces". Thus nothing to do with it being single line.

Answer (score 1):

1. You apparently omitted **return** keyword from *renderList* method
2. You should have wrapped renderList method call in a root single element while returning from render function.
   As a side note, to achieve a better coding experience do not forget to define *defaultProps* static property in class based component and default ES2015 params in functional one

```
class Profile extends React.Component {
     static defaultProps = {
        booking: {
          first_item: {
            item_name: "First name"
          },
          second_item: {
            item_name: "Second name"
          }
        }
     }

    renderList = () => {
        const { booking } = this.props;  
        return booking ? Object.keys(booking).map(x => <div>{booking[x].item_name}</div>) : null 
    }

    render() {
        return (
          <div>
           {this.renderList()} 
          </div>  
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: "You should have wrapped renderList method call in a root single element while returning from render function."  **If** you mean returning arrays don't work then: Nope, arrays work just fine [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/pyzzxxwx1j).